# Can I automatically generate a jquery block that does the same thing to different elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For simplicity, let's say I have a list of elements "#a1, a2, a3, a4..." and another list "#b1, b2, b3, b4...". I want `#b1` to show when I click `#a1`, I want `#b2` to show when I click `#a2`, and so on.

I could just write:

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $("b1).show();
});
$("#a2").click(function() {
  $("b2).show();
});
...
```

and so on. But if the list gets longer, that's going to be a lot of code.

Is there some way to automatically generate the jQuery? Here's some really rough rails-y pseudocode to illustrate what I want to do:

```
for (ids a1 - a99).each do |id|
  $("#a[id]").click(function() {
    $("#b[id]).show();
  });
end
```

Comment: Add a common class `a` to all the `a` elements, then `$(".a").click(function() {
  $('#' + this.id.replace('a', 'b')).show();
});
`

Comment: Can you share the html sample also

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but to give a proper solution you need to share the html sample

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an id - add a class. And use the following scheme

```
$( ".classA" ).click( function() {
    // get index of clicked element among elements with classA
    var index = $( ".classA" ).index( this );  
    // show element from classB with same index as clicked element
    $( ".classB" ).eq( index ).show();  
} );
```

A simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xjseca5d/

Answer (score 0):

use `substr()` to cut out the integer part (or use `parseInt()` that would only return the integer value included) and then use:
`$(".myControls").on("click", function(){
   $("#b"+ //the id in question).show();
});` `.myControls` being a selector for all your elements that need to be connected with that function.

Answer (score 0):

use a [starts-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and get the number using regex.

```
$('[id^="a"]').click(function(){
   var number = /\d+/.exec(this.id)[0];
   $('#b' + number).show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a loop may be sufficient. Attach all the handlers in the `document ready`.

```
// arr is an array of int, according to your DOM
$.each(arr, function(){
  $("#a"+this).click(function() {
    $("#b"+this).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('div[id^="a"]').on("click",function(){
    this.id.replace('a', 'b')).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class 'a' to all 'a' elements, 
Add a class 'b' to all 'b' elements,

attach a click event on the class 'a', replace the letter 'a'in ID by 'b'.

```
$('.a').click(function(){
   $('#'+this.id.replace('a','b')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For advanced case, I recommend this awesome plugin : 
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

You will be able to select your elements with a regex pattern like this :

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ?
                matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels, '')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^s+|s+$/g, ''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

alert($(":regex(id,a[0-9]{2})").length);

$(":regex(id,a[0-9]{2})").click(function() {
    var numberPart = /\d+/.exec(this.id)[0];
    alert($("#b" + numberPart).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a9">a9</div>
<div id="b99">b99</div>
<div id="a99">a99</div>
```